# Cordova application located on server (not on device) - Events do not fire

Tags: javascript, java, android, cordova, event-handling

I am writing a cordova (version 6) application for an Android 4.4 device. Here I am trying to catch the button-press events, e.g. <kbd>volume-down</kbd> button. Unfortunately I need to host the app on a server. Meaning all the html, css and js files are loaded remotely. Whereas the `index.html` of the app itself only contains:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <title>My App</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function init() {
        window.location.href="http://example.com:3000/myapp";
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body id="body" onload="init();">
  </body>
</html>
```

On the server-side the cordova-js gets successfully injected with:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/cordova.js"></script>`

I have built the cordova-js by myself, using this repository and their documentation: https://github.com/apache/cordova-js

---

Most of the server-side cordova code is running fine! E.g. I have added some plugins which all work (wifi-information, show-toast-messages, and so on...). But unfortunately the button-listeners for <kbd>menu</kbd>, <kbd>back</kbd>, <kbd>volup</kbd>, <kbd>voldown</kbd> are not working anymore! They used to work, when the cordova code was loaded directly on the device, but since I put in on a remote server it doesn't work anymore.

**JS-file from Server:**

```
//Gets called from the body-tag of the html-site - works!
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

function onDeviceReady() {
  //This works!
  console.log("onDeviceReady");

  //This doesn't do anything (but also no error messages)
  navigator.app.overrideButton("backbutton", true);
  navigator.app.overrideButton("menubutton", true);
  document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
  document.addEventListener("volumeupbutton", onVolumeUpKeyDown, false);
  document.addEventListener("menubutton", onMenuKeyDown, false);

  //Plugins that are loaded from here all work!
}

function onMenuKeyDown(event) {
  //This doesn't work
  console.log("menu pressed");
}

function onBackKeyDown(event) {
  //This doesn't work
  console.log("back pressed");
}

function onVolumeUpKeyDown() {
  //This doesn't work
  console.log("Volume up pressed");
}
```

Can someone tell me, why this code isn't working anymore and help me fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this...

```
    //Gets called from the body-tag of the html-site - works!
    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    function onDeviceReady() {
      //This works!
      console.log("onDeviceReady");
    }



    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);

    document.addEventListener("volumeupbutton", onVolumeUpKeyDown, false);

    document.addEventListener("menubutton", onMenuKeyDown, false);

    function onMenuKeyDown(event) {

      console.log("menu pressed");
    }

    function onBackKeyDown(event) {

      console.log("back pressed");
    }

    function onVolumeUpKeyDown() {

      console.log("Volume up pressed");
    }
```